# Scopes in Python Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module code :

```
X = 88 
def f():
    global X 
    X = 99
```

And another file which uses this module :

```
from First import X,f
X = 11
f()
print(X)
```

Now as per my understanding since we are explicitly importing symbols x and f they should become part of the importing modules namespace .

And since the function f changes the global X . The answer should be 99.

But that does not seem to be the case , as the output is 11.

Please help me understand why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the `from module import ...` syntax, you create **new** names, that are bound to the same objects as the names in the original modules. Those names are *independent*.

After importing you have this:

```
First.X ----\
             |--> 88
another.X --/
```

You then set `another.X` *only* to `11`, so you have this:

```
First.X --------> 88

another.X ------> 11
```

and after you call `f()`, you have this:

```
First.X --------> 99

another.X ------> 11
```

You could instead import *just* the module; that binds the name `First` to point to the module object:

```
import First
first.X = 11
first.f()
print(first.X)
```

Now all code operates on `First.X` only.

You may want to read up on how [Python names and objects work](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot . So basically using the from statement (from <modulename> import *) implies that we just can use the objects inside the imported module without qualifying them with the module name . But for all practical purposes it is the same as just writing import <modulename>

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: `from module import *` creates new names in your namespace for every name available in `module` (what is available depends on the `module.__dir__`, or `[name for name in dir(module) if name[0] != '_']` if there is no `module.__dir__`).

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: `import module` on the other hand only ever sets the name `module` in your namespace. Nothing more. So no, that's not true, `import module` is completely different from `from module import *`.